# Material UI React: Problems with the footer not staying at the bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, footer

## **We have an application made in react and we use material ui.**

we want the footer to only display at the bottom of the page and not scroll with the content.

We would like a footer like without scroll which is just in the below of all components.

We tried different solutions in css like display:flex, position: absolut but it doesn't resolve.
Here is one footer code

### **App Layout**

```
1. CSS Part

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appWrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "100vh",
    overflow: "hidden",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  appBodyWrapper: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  appFooterWrapper: {
    height: " 28px",
    minHeight: "28px",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    padding: "10px 10px"
  },
}));


**2. JSX Part**

      <div className={classes.appWrapper}>
        <div className={classes.appBodyWrapper}>
componets
        </div>
        <footer className={classes.appFooterWrapper}></footer>
      </div>
```

This is the link of the last test I did https://internazionaleauto-4dro9vwqr-internazionaleauto.vercel.app/

We would also like the footer to be seen immediately from the desktop and not after a scroll, also as you can see there is a problem that I have to scroll twice to see the footer instead from mobile I would like to see it only at the end of the page and for it to remain there

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to fix it to the bottom of the page. By adding this code to your footer it should work.

```
  appFooterWrapper: {
  height: " 28px",
  minHeight: "28px",
  backgroundColor: "#000",
  padding: "10px 10px",
  position: fixed,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 100vw,
},
```

Comment: We used your suggestion, but the footer is sticky and scrolling.

Same as previous one